# Why does my form submit an empty string to php file in ie but not chrome or mozilla?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

My goal is, when somebody fills out the form, for the information to be submitted on click of the submit button, to the php file, which in turn will email me with the form values. It works in chrome and mozilla apparently, but not in Edge or Safari. I've searched everywhere for an answer but I can't find anything. What am I not including? Did I code it wrong? I just cannot figure it out.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="PMOM.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo|Fira+Sans|Muli|Nunito|Open+Sans|Roboto+Condensed|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Photo Mirror of Memories</title>

    <style>

    h1{
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .main{
      padding-top: 80px;
      height: 1500px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgb(82, 117, 139);
    }

    .main_form{
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 100px 200px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      height: 700px;
      width: 800px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 15px;

    }

    .type-field{
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .package-select{
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    .comments{
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 10px 0;
    }


    @media (max-width: 600px) {

    .main{
      color: white;
    }

      .main_form{
        width: 50%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: inherit;
        padding: 0px;
        /* border: 1px solid red; */
      }
      .type-field{
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        /* border: 1px solid red; */
      }

      .comments{
        width: 200px;
          /* border: 1px solid red; */
        height: 40px;
        margin: 10px 0;
      }

    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="main">
      <h1 style="color: white;">Please fill out your information</h1>
      <div class="main_form">
        <form method="post" action="/emailSending.php">
          <input class="type-field" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"><br>
          <input class="type-field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
          <input class="type-field" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
          <input class="type-field" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>

          <input class="package-select" type="radio" name="package" value="Basic" checked> Basic Package
          <br>
          <input class="package-select" type="radio" name="package" value="Deluxe"> Deluxe Package
          <br>
          <input class="package-select" type="radio" name="package" value="Premium"> Premium Package
          <br>
          <input class="comments" type="text-field" name="notes" placeholder="Comments">
          <button type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>

        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div id="app2"></div> -->
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

    <?php
    $fname=$_POST[fname];
    $lname=$_POST[lname];
    $email=$_POST[email];
    $phone=$_POST[phone];
    $package=$_POST[package];
    $comments=$_POST[comments];
    $to='email@email.com';
    $subject="Customer Package";
    $message="Name: ".$fname."\n"."Last name: ".$lname."\n"."Email: ".$email."\n"."Phone number: ".$phone."\n"."Package: ".$package;
    $headers="From: ".$email;

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "<h1>Thank you</h1>"


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your PHP variables are wrong. Note that I added single quotes to your post elements. I'm not sure how that could possibly be working with any browser.

Other than what I did below, I see no reason at all that it wouldn't work with any browser.

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $package=$_POST['package'];
    $comments=$_POST['comments'];
```

Comment: He's not wrong, why the downvote? I don't get how the form works at all. Also leave your form action empty if you want the post to occur on the same page, except that's the link to that page

Comment: Thanks @comphonia - Some people downvote anything they slightly think is off. Some sort of power trip.

Comment: I added the single quotes but its still not working. On a side note, I couldn't figure out how to separate the code when I uploaded the example. The html is in one file and the php code is in a .php file. If there is a better way to go about doing this please tell me I have no idea how to do it any other way.

Comment: Scratch that, I just tried it again after clearing the cache and I believe it did work. Thank you so much. It is weird that it worked for chrome and mozilla. Not sure why. And I don't know why you got downvoted either. Your solution was right on! Thank you again!

Comment: Please do me a favor and mark it as solved then. It would be appreciated.